# EPPlus missing dependency

Tags: c#, epplus

I added EPPlus and usage of OfficeOpenXml to my project.
However, when I run my project I get this errors and warning :

Warning :

```
The referenced assembly "EPPlus" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.
```

Errors :

```
The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can someone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, like the warning says, is that EPPlus references an assembly (`System.Web`) that is not in the .NET v4.0 Client Framework. You might want to target the full .NET v4.0 instead of the Client framework.

**Update** This has step-by-step instructions on changing the target framework for a project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx In your project that's trying to reference EPPlus, instead of .NET 4.0 Client Profile, choose .NET 4.0.