# EPPlus The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#-2.0, epplus

Hi I am using EPPlus to create excel in c# 2.0. I have added the reference of "EPPlus.dll" and also added

```
using OfficeOpenXML;
```

but when i am trying to run the solution its giving the follwoing error.

Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Warning 1:

```
The primary reference "EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
```

Warning 2:

```
The primary reference "EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 9):

This solved the problem for me :

[Errors on EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907629/errors-on-epplus)

just change the target of your proyect from ".Net 4.0 Client Profile" to just ".Net 4.0"

Answer (score 3):

Rolling back to a prior version worked for me.

Comment: Version 4.5.3.2 doesn't work with MVC.NET with target framework 4.5.2. Need to roll back to version 4.5.3.1

Answer (score 2):

This could happen when you migrate project from one computer to another. The solution in my case was

1. Open the project/website in Visual Studio
2. Save it as solution (if it is website) - **important**
3. Go to Nuget for this solution. It will give you an error that some plugs are installed incorrect and needs to be restored. Click restore button but it might actually **not** work
4. Check EPPLUS in the nuget, select properties and uncheck from solution to uninstall it.
5. Reinstall it again. This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Even,I had this type of error in past.So,what you have to do to solve this error.
Firstly, you have check to **EPPLUS.dll** in bin folder.If you will not see in your bin folder than add it .
secondly,if you see than ,right click on reference folder/add reference/click on browse/add **EPPLUS.dll**

If you don't have that download  from below link:[enter link description here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)

Answer (score 1):

The error was told that the epplus has an indirect reference to the windowbase 3.0 which do not included in .net framework 2.0 then i manage to find that dll located in

"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll". thank to this question [WindowsBase Version 3.0.0.0 in Global Assembly Cache](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windowsbase-version-3000-in-global-assembly-cache/28faa3a0-aa9c-4fc5-9baa-a9cfc3713a25)

So i just referenced that dll to my project and the error was gone. this cloud be help.